# Exchange h3 header text with some other text

Tags: jquery

I've got a header with some other elements inside. E.g.:

```
<h3 id="header" >
<span ...></span>
TITLE
<img ...>
</h3>
```

I want to replace `"TITLE"` with some other text. Thats what I tried:

```
$("#header").contents().filter(function(){return this.nodeType == 3;}).text("some other text");
```

But nothing happens here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know, why the upper solution worked in JSFiddle but not for my code. However, I found another solution that worked well for me:

```
$("#header").contents().filter(function(){return this.nodeType == 3;}).remove();
$("header").append('some other text');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
$('#header').contents().filter(function () {
    return this.nodeType === 3 && $.trim(this.nodeValue).length;
}).replaceWith('some other text');
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Swc5u/)**

Comment: Thanks, it works in JSFiddle, but somehow not in my code. Have to revise it again... Can u tell me why the text() function is not working?

Comment: I'm not sure why `.text()` is not working, but it's probably because you cannot use `.text()` on text node, you can only replace it. Hopefully you can figure out the reason why it's not working on your site :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap a class around the text and then use replace with

`$("#header .title-class").replaceWith( "New heading" );`

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work for me, because the header is autogenerated by a JQuery function